# problem with rendering content using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect, saga

I am showing list of coupons based on category selected using useEffect and saga.

```
const initialState = {
    is_loading: true,
    coupon_data: [],
    error_msg: '',
}
```

This is my initial state state. `is_loading` set to true default so that whenever component get visited it shows loader first, after that `getCoupon()` get dispatch from `useEffect` which hit api and get response asynchronously using redux-saga,then `is_loading` is set to false and  based on  response `coupon_data` or `error_msg` get updated.

this is component:

```
    const Couponlist = props => {
    const [coupon, updateCoupon] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.coupon.is_loading) {
            updateCoupon(<Loader />);
            props.getCoupon(props.match.params.category)
        } else if (!props.coupon.is_loading && props.coupon.coupon_data.length) {
            const coupon_data = props.coupon.coupon_data.map(coupon => {
                return (<div key={coupon.id} className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                    <img className="card-img-top" src={coupon.banner}
                        alt={"Card image cap " + coupon.id} />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">Outlet : {coupon.outlet}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">Category : {coupon.category}</p>
                        <p className="card-text">Merchant : {coupon.merchant}</p>
                        <p className="card-text">Price : {coupon.coupon_price}</p>
                        <p className="card-text">Valid From : {coupon.valid_from}</p>
                        <p className="card-text">Valid To : {coupon.valid_to}</p>
                        <p className="card-text">Trending : {coupon.trending}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>)
            })
            updateCoupon(coupon_data);
        } else if (!props.coupon.is_loading && props.coupon.error_msg !== '') {
            updateCoupon(props.coupon.error_msg);
        }

    }, [props.match.params.category, props.coupon])

    return coupon;
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { coupon: state.coupon };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getCoupon: category => dispatch(getCouponeInit(category))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Couponlist);
```

When component get visited first time `is_loading` is `true` so `if (props.coupon.is_loading)` becomes true and component render loader and request api for data.

after getting data from api `is_loading` is set to false and component render coupon data.

Now the problem is when user click on another category `Couponlist` component get visited again but this time `is_loading` is set to false and also there is old data there in store. So in this case instaed of requesting for new data component simply render old available data.

How can I handle this condition ?

Comment: do `props.coupon.coupon_data` showing  updated value in in useEffect?

Comment: states `coupon_data` property get updated only once when app get initialise ( `is_loading` is set to true at that moment ) after that if user click on other category api does not get call due to `is_loading` and component simply render old data

Answer (score 0):

you can add function inside UseEffect to clean up your component, try to add that at the bottom of the function useEffect

```
() => { your clean up code here }
```